Unable to run WinUI3 App on Windows Server 2016 (V-1607 OS Build 14393.2248) (Virtual Machine)
I have developed one WinUI3 application and I tried to run in Windows Server 2016 V-1607(OS Build 14393.2248) (VM),
I was getting below issue (Please check the image), when I tried to run in my VM which is having Windows Server 2026.
am I missing something here?
What is the minimum version to run this?


The apps are not always just static .exe you can copy over. Have you read the official doc about WinUI3 (WinAppSDK) deployment? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/package-and-deploy/deploy-overview

If you're using a packaged output, you need to deploy it before running it. You can only directly execute an unpackaged output.

@SimonMourier I am trying to run WinUI 3 app through VS 2022 only. There only I am facing issue? Am I missing something.

Whether have you tried to check the Deploy option of the Project contexts in Configuration Manager?

According to Windows App SDK and supported Windows releases, Windows Server 2019 and Windows Server 2022 are supported but Windows Server 2016 is not supported.
